# Can people store a js/jquery/ajax history?

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, service, get

I have a web service that is called via GET in an ajax.

Someone pointed out that we created a vulnerability in our page because when the user logs out,  GET calls are stored in browser history(I've tested this and so far found this claim to be false and so far I cant store it in history).

Is there any way(via plugins or w/e) people cans store script calls in a browser history? If so, does changing the call method to POST really solve anything.

IMPORTANT: The security threat is not because they can try to generate a request(We have security ids for that), the problem is if they can read sensible information in the url.

Comment: HTTP requests may be logged w/o your consent or knowledge at locations you have no control over. The program must be written in a way that replaying any previous requests is not a security risk.

Comment: Tag the get request with a timestamp and only allow those requests within X number of MS/S/M to execute server side. Then it doesn't matter because the history/copy-paste/user-land get requests won't return results. This isn't a security practice. If you need security you need to authenticate your users.

Comment: We do have security for that. I am not concerned with them trying to replicate the  request, only reading the sensible information in the URL.

Comment: use [jwt](https://jwt.io/)?